# Какой тип верстки изучать?

Tags: html, css

Только начал изучать веб-разработку и появился вопрос: какой тип верстки изучать, блочный или табличный? Можно ли задавая в css position потом оптимизировать сайт под разные разрешения, потому что все, что я пока что видел оптимизируется в табличной верстке. Дело в том, что столкнулся с тем, что указывая для блоков position начало наваливаться все больше и больше проблем, одно наезжать на другое. Вот я и подумал, что возможно табличная верстка оптимальный вариант. Стоит ли использовать position вообще, а если нет, то как тогда размещать блоки в пространстве сайта, не используя его. 
P.S. Не кидайте камнями, я только учусь :)

Comment: Табличная верстка уже в основном не используется.

Comment: Сейчас на флексах все

Comment: position нужно использовать, но нужно понимать когда его использовать. Т.е. не нужно делать всю вёрсту на `position: absolute`. В изучении - лучше изучить всё, не прям "от корки до корки", хоть бы поверхностно, чтобы понимать что от чего отличается и как работает.

Comment: Если у вас возникает такой вопрос, то вы учитесь по каким-то древним ресурсам. Я начинал учиться верстать ровно десять лет назад, уже тогда вопрос таблицы или дивы не стоял.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Таблицы для оформления контента использовали этак лет пятнадцать назад. Теперь это считается не комильфо, да и более простые и продвинутые варианты появились.

Один из них, который стал достаточно популярен за последние несколько лет, это flex. Позволяет определять как элементы отображаются друг относительно друга, и имеет жуткое количество опций. За примером далеко идти не надо. Этот сайт использует flex в том числе чтобы разделить центральную полосу, и полосы по правой и левой стороне.

А чтобы в вас не бросались камнями, используйте таблицы исключительно по назначению, то есть для того, чтобы показывать данные, которые должны быть представлены в форме таблицы.

Comment: "жуткое количество опций" у grid'ов. Флекс на порядок проще для понимания и реализации. Но меньше возможностей, если сравнивать с grid'ами.

Comment: Забыли упамянуть, что все эти флексы и гриды на момент 2020 г. все еще с жуткими багами и чем старее браузер у пользователя, тем этих багов больше. Конкретно этот сайт из-за флексов полностью не работает в Internet Explorer последней версии. Конечно большинство пользователей браузер обновляют, но упомянуть про совместимость все-же стоит.

Comment: В дополнение к комментарию NoSkill: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 2):

Соглашусь с @ArseniMourzenko, и добавлю свои 5 копеек.

Сейчас на всех современных сайтов(или почти всех) используется исключительно блочная верстка с использованием `grid`, `flex`, `float`, Лидером является `flex` из-за поддержки и удобности и гибкости. Что касательно `Grid`а - стараются сейчас все чаще использовать "Новинку", ведь буквально как пару лет он начал нормально поддерживаться во всех современных браузерах. Также вы можете его смешивать(использовать grid+flex).

Ранее использовали подход `float+clearfix`(когда была плохая поддержка `flex`). И сейчас можно встретить сайты работающих с этим подходом.
Что касается table, вам придется и этот подход понять как работает. Например в тех случаях, когда Вам нужно сделать верстку для технологий, какие плохо поддерживают HTML5 и CSS3.

Например:

1. Создания страниц для почтовой рассылки (mail-layout);
2. Генерация html в pdf, doc, docx и другие документы;
3. Приложение которое использует интерфейс в виде таблицы(например, Excel-онлайн) и т.п

P.S. Не всегда стоит использовать таблицу для своего предназначения. Например, вывод таблицу товаров. Одна из причин отказа от таблиц это отсутствия гибкости в адаптации сайта под устройство с не большим разрешением (мобильные телефоны или планшеты). Если таблица содержит не большое количество столбцов до 3-4 - то все хорошо. А если больше, лучше использовать блочную верстку и внешне сделать похожую на таблицу.